# Rails Delayed Jobs testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, delayed-job

I wanted to test a delayed job that in its performs function calls and external API with some data and if successful updates a record in the database.

```
class IncomeUploadJob < Struct.new(:person)
  def perform

      success, result = PersonService.upload_finances(person.income)
      if success
          rich = RichPeople.new(:name => person.name,
                                :income => person.income,
                                :richness_level => result["richness_level"])
          rich.save!
        end
      else
        Rails.logger.warn("Upload income job failed")
      end
  end
end
```

I wanted to write a simple test for this where I can just call that method and in the end, after the job is completed I could test the Db for the new record. Some guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Rspec test**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe IncomeUploadJob do
  describe '#perform' do
    let(:person) { create(:person) }

    before { stub_api_call }

    context 'when success' do
      it 'creates RichPeople record' do
        IncomeUploadJob.new.perform
        RichPeople.reload

        expect(RichPeople.count).not_to eq(0)
      end
    end

    def stub_api_call
      stub_request(:post, 'https://apiurl.com/access_token').to_return(
        body: fixture('access_token.json'),
        headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

**Explanation:**

- `let(:person) { create(:person) }` this may not require in your case, if required, you can create `person` factory and create person record
- You can mock/stub your API calls as I did in `stub_api_call` method, create `fixure` file if API response is big otherwise you can directly add it here instead of fixure. You can stub more than one API as per your requirement, I just did one.
- `IncomeUploadJob.new.perform` calls the job.

Thanks, let me know if you have any other queries in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mock on your service with something like:

```rb
describe IncomeUploadJob do
  context 'with successful API request' do
    subject { described_class.perform_now(person) }
 
    let(:person) { create(:person) } # assume you're using Faker
    let(:double_finance_upload) { [true, {"richness_level" => 42} ]}
  
    before do
      expect(PersonService).to receive(:upload_finances).with(person.income).and_return(double_finance_upload)
    end

    it 'creates a new rich person' do
      expect{subject}.to change{RichPeople.count}.by(1)
    end
  end
end
```